# Issue installing windows 10 on a new SSD drive

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bios, uefi

I bought a new Samsung SATA SSD and initialized it as a GPT drive. I want to use this drive to boot and run Windows 10, but have run into many issues which are way over my head.

Eventually, I fully reset my PC because Windows was not booting on any of the drives that it did previously.

I know the following:

- My BIOS mode in Windows, displayed under System Information, is UEFI.
- My new SSD drive (on which I want boot and run Windows) is a GPT drive, and so is the drive currently running Windows.
- When I previously tried installing Windows on my SSD, I received a message that it couldn't be installed on a GPT drive, which contradicts the previous fact.
- My BIOS is set to "legacy+UEFI" mode, and when I switch it to "UEFI (only)" mode, a lot of my boot options disappear, including the SSD drive.

I've read some info about changing Secure Boot and CSM settings and (if I understand correctly) the boot mode used while installing Windows 10 to make a difference, although don't understand what effect these things changes would have.

I want to use UEFI mode since it seems to be the better option, and I believe most things are already set up for this to be possible. It just seems that a few settings need to be tweaked.

I don't want to run into the issue of having to reset my PC again. Any advice is appreciated, but please understand I am not tech-savvy and will likely have a few questions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode?view=windows-11

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style?view=windows-11

Comment: I think these 2 links answer most questions one could have, let us know if you have more questions

Comment: so, my SSD is already a GPT drive, and my PC is in UEFI mode. that just means that i have to change my settings in BIOS to boot from a UEFI drive, right? however, the SSD disappears when i switch the boot mode setting to UEFI from legacy+UEFI. is that because i haven't installed windows on it yet?

Comment: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ssd-not-detecting-in-uefi-mode-but-working-fine-in-legacy-mode.3679911/ or https://www.google.com/search?q=ssd+disappears+when+i+switch+to+uefi

Comment: Get the Microsoft Windows 10 media (Microsoft Media Creation Link), make a bootable USB Key and just install Windows.  Should work

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: i have tried that, and it forced me to have to reset my entire pc in order to run windows again. apparently it sounds like i have to install windows from a USB drive while my BIOS is in UEFI mode... so i'll try that

Comment: thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Yep, exactly. Good luck! UEFI is better (faster+more secure)

Comment: please understand i am not tech savvy    ....   Make sure you have any data backed up and install just the blank drive (just one drive) and install Windows normally. That will work for sure.

Comment: when i switched the BIOS to UEFI, mode my usb drive with the windows installer disappeared, so i couldn’t boot from there

Comment: Is the USB stick FAT32? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/most-drives-disappear-when-disselecting-legacy/48ceb251-ee5f-407b-93d8-19a6489df692

Comment: yes. it is FAT32

Comment: i switched the BIOS to UEFI, mode my usb drive   .....   I have not seen this with a vanilla USB creation (Microsoft) and install. Maybe create a USB Key with FDISK and format the drive.

Comment: i had forgotten to set the hard disk boot priority. i’m now installing windows from the usb drive. my question now is, once the install is done, i should be able to boot from my SSD right?

Comment: install seemed like it worked. now i’m back in BIOS and all my boot options no longer have unique names pertaining to the drives (Samsung EVO 870 etc.) there is UEFI OS and windows boot manager and UEFI Hard Disk:UEFI OS

Comment: Windows 10 creates recovery, UEFI and data partitions on one drive, so it should start.  I use Samsung EVO drives on my desktop and two laptop computers.

Comment: it’s only booting from the usb drive with the windows installer. there’s no option to boot from the samsung ssd. i could also boot it from my hdd that had windows before trying all of this, so only the ssd is missing

Comment: i successfully installed windows onto the new SSD, but there is still no option to boot from it in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

> When I previously tried installing Windows on my SSD, I received a message that it couldn't be installed on a GPT drive, which contradicts the previous fact.

The most common reason for this is because your booted into your installation media using Legacy. If you have Legacy + UEFI enabled, you may find multiple boot options in your boot menu that is related to your installation media. If one does not work, try another.

If you cannot find any UEFI booting option for your installation media, consider remake a USB installation drive using Windows Image Creation tool. Check [Windows website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) for relevant info.

> My BIOS is set to "legacy+UEFI" mode, and when I switch it to "UEFI (only)" mode, a lot of my boot options disappear, including the SSD drive.

You do not need your SSD to appear in your UEFI boot option **BEFORE** you actually install Windows on it. In UEFI mode, during installation, the installer will create an EFI partition on your SSD, which eventually cause it to appear in your boot options.